# What are some good international, English language physics grad programs?

Tags: soft-question, education

I am looking into physics PhD programs and I would love to take the opportunity to live abroad (again). I know there are some well-known, technical, international universities like IIT in India and KAIST in Saudi Arabia.

What universities offer PhD (or MS) Physics degrees with classes taught in English, but are not in an English speaking country?

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet might be the EPFL or [École polytechnique fédérale de Lausanne](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%C3%89cole_Polytechnique_F%C3%A9d%C3%A9rale_de_Lausanne) in Switzerland. Their master courses are in English, while others are in French. They also have strong links with CERN and produce a lot of amazing research in a wide variety of fields. (they even have an on campus [tokamak fusion reactor](http://crpp.epfl.ch/Research#faq-273530) and [a good ole fission reactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CROCUS))

Here's the brief of their [physics program](http://sb.epfl.ch/physics).

> Condensed Matter Physics has always been very important to our
>   faculty, with innovative research programs on novel materials at many
>   scales, from bulk to surface, to granular materials and composites, to
>   biomaterials, down to molecular materials and nanostructures. Ok
>   Quantum devices and quantum photonics as well as fast spectroscopy are
>   also an important subject of research, both under the experimental,
>   the applicative and theoretical aspects.
>
> Our faculty has also strong links with CERN , for high energy physics,
>   JET for the fusion programme and PSI  for its synchrotron and nuclear
>   facilities. Our students and researchers have access to a "zero power"
>   nuclear reactor on site.
>
> Cosmology is studied at the associated Sauverny Observatory (Geneva)
>   as well as by theoretical groups on site. Biophysics completes the
>   gamut of our research and didactical activities, the main interests
>   being the imaging and probing of live samples, as well as the
>   mechanical and topological properties of cells and DNA.

Comment: Merci beaucoup!

Answer (score 4):

India: The Indian Institute of Science is quite good. (A lot better than the IITs, at least in the sciences)

Europe: ETH Zurich, University of Basel, German universities like Technical University Munich, Bonn University, etc., University of Utrecht in Netherlands

Singapore: National University of Singapore and Nanyang Technological University are quite good

Israel: Weizmann Institute of Science, Hebrew University of Jerusalem (for these two you might have to check about language of instruction)

If you want to be really adventurous, you could try University of Tokyo, in Japan.

It all depends on your funding situation. The European Unis are best in this regard.

Comment: Thanks!  I have looked into the Weizmann Institute and the instruction is in English.  I don't know about Hebrew University.  And, as for funding, the Weizmann Institute is always free... if you're accepted that is.  :)